# How to dynamically assert on word boundaries in raw text while pre processing a document?

Tags: java, python, nlp

Firstly, I have researched about this and found matches that closely deal with word boundaries in a sentences or at the maximum, suggest the use of tokenizers which is not what I am looking for. My query is as follows:

My current task is related to preprocessing an unstructured data that follow this pipeline - conversion of PDF to TXT files that gives out few sentences like this:

> s e ar c h t h i s s t r ing for a def e c t

what I actually want is :

> search this string for a defect

All I'm looking for are few possible approaches to such kinds of scenarios in NLP. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're looking for a tokenizer, even if you don't think you are looking for a tokenizer.  If the content you're taking from the PDF uniformly uses a character separator that isn't the same as the word separator, you could alternatively replace/remove that.

Comment: Are you manually extracting text from the PDF files? That's painful. Try using a [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pdf&submit=search) to do the extraction.

Comment: This probably belongs on programming.stackexchange.com, and with just an nlp tag.

Comment: @tristan can you elaborate on how a tokenizer would solve this issue as a tokenizer on fundamental level splits, say, a sentence into words based on whitespaces, right? Also, The PDFBOX for Java and pdfminer for python dont seem to eliminate this "junk".

Comment: @PM2Ring No. Like I mentioned in the above comment, I use those two libraries with minimal success rate. Any suggestions would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alseambusher/columbus/master/words-by-frequency.txt) for the word list.

```
from math import log

# Build a cost dictionary, assuming Zipf's law and cost = -math.log(probability).
words = open("words-by-frequency.txt").read().split()
wordcost = dict((k, log((i+1)*log(len(words)))) for i,k in enumerate(words))
maxword = max(len(x) for x in words)

def infer_spaces(s):
    """Uses dynamic programming to infer the location of spaces in a string
    without spaces."""

    # Find the best match for the i first characters, assuming cost has
    # been built for the i-1 first characters.
    # Returns a pair (match_cost, match_length).
    def best_match(i):
        candidates = enumerate(reversed(cost[max(0, i-maxword):i]))
        return min((c + wordcost.get(s[i-k-1:i], 9e999), k+1) for k,c in candidates)

    # Build the cost array.
    cost = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
        c,k = best_match(i)
        cost.append(c)

    # Backtrack to recover the minimal-cost string.
    out = []
    i = len(s)
    while i>0:
        c,k = best_match(i)
        assert c == cost[i]
        out.append(s[i-k:i])
        i -= k

    return " ".join(reversed(out))

s = 's e ar c h t h i s s t r ing for a def e c t'.replace(' ','')
print(infer_spaces(s))
```